# POST method through node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am writing a simple node.js for a REST API call to create object through POST method and get the response code. But while running the script I get "0 passing" .

Here is my code:

```js
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://example.org',
  headers: 
   { 'content-type': 'application/vnd.nativ.mio.v1+json',
     authorization: 'Basic hashedTokenHere' },
  //body: '{\n\n"name": "My JS TEST",\n"type": "media-asset"\n\n}' 
  };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(response.statusCode, body);
    } 

 
});
```

Can anyone help to to run it successfully and get the response code?

Thanks!

Comment: there is error in your configuration

Answer (score 1):

I calling my local API hope this will make thing get clear. It's work for me

This my API

```
var  express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app=express()
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/api',function(req,res)
        {
    res.status(200).send(req.body.name+"hi");
})
app.listen(8080,function(){
           console.log("start");
           })
```

Now, through Request, i will request this post method

```
var request = require('request');
// Set the headers
var headers = {
    'User-Agent':       'Super Agent/0.0.1',
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth,
    }
var postData = {
  name: 'test',
  value: 'test'
}
// Configure the request
var options = {
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api',
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    headers: headers,
    body: postData
}

// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        // Print out the response body and head
        console.log("body = "+body+"  head= "+response.statusCode)
    }
})
```